# Sidekiq delete or kill job inside a middleware

Tags: sidekiq

Is it recommended to delete or kill failed job inside a middleware? I was not able to find any documentation on this matter in the wiki. FWIW, I am using sidekiq-pro.

One thing I noticed was even though I had the correct job id, the job was not getting killed. Is it possible that the sidekiq job gets assigned a different id when it is enqueued?

```
STATUSES = {
  canceled:        6,
  failure:         9,
  expired:         10
}.freeze

def call(worker, message, queue)
  key = message['args'][0]
  jid = message['jid']

  if key.present?
    // status_id fetched from database
    status_id = Req.find(key).status

    if STATUSES.values.include?(status_id)
      if killable?(message)
        job = Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.find_job(jid)
        // kill doesn't always succeed because job cannot be found
        job.kill
      end
    end
  end
  yield
end

def killable?(message)
  message.key?('retry_count')
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to 'kill' the job, just return instead of yielding.  The job will silently succeed without executing anything.  You can use this method as a reference to send a job to the Dead queue:

```
def send_to_morgue(msg)
  logger.info { "Adding dead #{msg["class"]} job #{msg["jid"]}" }
  payload = Sidekiq.dump_json(msg)
  DeadSet.new.kill(payload, notify_failure: false)
end
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/148afbf0779b246d82a95fa1b6b984c67ebf6229/lib/sidekiq/job_retry.rb#L194-L198

Comment: Thanks for responding Mike, I was wondering when you would show up :D
But in this case I do need to kill the job, because we don't want it anymore in the retry queue. It won't succeed if it gets of those statuses.

Comment: Ah I get what you're saying, so that means it should also disappear from the retry queue. I will give this a shot and report back to you.

Comment: The job is moved from the retry set to the queue for execution.  There's nothing to remove from the retry set.

Comment: Okay. Please allow me two phrase my question better: I want to move the job with that `jid` to a dead queue base on my conditional check. How can I do that? I don't want to process it again.

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb#L151

Comment: Okay, this seems to do the trick. But I feel guilty for calling a private method. Can you update your answer above so I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Both the links are dead! @MikePerham

Comment: Can you please paste the code instead? :) @MikePerham